# TypeError: _enzyme2.default.configure is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, webpack-3

So recently, I migrated from React 15.4.2 to React 16.0.0.
Here are my current versions in project:

```
{  
    "jest":{  
        "verbose":true,
        "automock":false,
        "testRegex":"\\.test\\.js$",
        "moduleNameMapper":{  
            "config":"<rootDir>/src/config/test.js",
            "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$":"<rootDir>/src/__tests__/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
            "\\.(css|less|scss)$":"<rootDir>/src/__tests__/__mocks__/styleMock.js",
            "\\Api.(js)$":"<rootDir>/src/__tests__/__mocks__/apiMock.js"
        },
        "coveragePathIgnorePatterns":[  
            "<rootDir>/src/utils/svgVisualization.js"
        ],
        "unmockedModulePathPatterns":[  
            "react"
        ],
        "moduleFileExtensions":[  
            "js",
            "json"
        ],
        "modulePathIgnorePatterns":[  
            "/node_modules/"
        ],
        "testPathIgnorePatterns":[  
            "/node_modules/"
        ],
        "setupFiles":[  
            "<rootDir>/src/__tests__/__mocks__/storageMock.js"
        ]
    },
    "main":"src/index.js",
    "scripts":{  
        "clean":"rimraf dist/*",
        "copy":"copyfiles -f ./src/index.html ./dist",
        "dist":"npm run clean && npm run copy && webpack --progress --bail --env dist -p",
        "dev":"npm run clean && npm run copy && webpack --progress --bail --env dev -p",
        "lint":"esw webpack.config.* src tools --color",
        "lint:watch":"npm run lint -- --watch",
        "release:major":"npm version prerelease && git push --follow-tags && npm publish --tag beta",
        "release:minor":"npm version prerelease && git push --follow-tags && npm publish --tag beta",
        "release:patch":"npm version prerelease && git push --follow-tags && npm publish --tag beta",
        "serve:dev":"webpack-dev-server --open --env dev",
        "serve:dist":"webpack-dev-server --open --env dist -p --progress",
        "open:src":"npm run serve:dev",
        "start":"npm-run-all --parallel open:src lint:watch",
        "test":"jest --coverage"
    },
    "devDependencies":{  
        "babel-core":"^6.7.6",
        "babel-eslint":"^7.1.0",
        "babel-jest":"^20.0.3",
        "babel-loader":"^6.2.4",
        "babel-plugin-istanbul":"^3.0.0",
        "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties":"^6.24.1",
        "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy":"^1.3.4",
        "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread":"^6.8.0",
        "babel-polyfill":"^6.9.0",
        "babel-preset-airbnb":"^2.0.0",
        "babel-preset-es2015":"^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-es2015-native-modules":"^6.6.0",
        "babel-preset-react":"^6.24.1",
        "chai":"^4.1.2",
        "copyfiles":"^1.0.0",
        "css-loader":"^0.28.7",
        "enzyme":"^3.1.0",
        "enzyme-adapter-react-16":"^1.0.1",
        "eslint":"^4.1.1",
        "eslint-config-airbnb":"^15.1.0",
        "eslint-loader":"^1.3.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import":"^2.2.0",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y":"^5.1.1",
        "eslint-plugin-react":"^7.1.0",
        "file-loader":"^1.1.4",
        "jest":"^21.2.1",
        "jest-enzyme":"^4.0.0",
        "karma":"^1.0.0",
        "karma-chai":"^0.1.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher":"^2.1.1",
        "karma-coverage":"^1.0.0",
        "karma-junit-reporter":"^1.0.0",
        "karma-mocha":"^1.0.1",
        "karma-mocha-reporter":"^2.0.3",
        "karma-phantomjs-launcher":"^1.0.0",
        "karma-sinon":"^1.0.5",
        "karma-sourcemap-loader":"^0.3.7",
        "karma-webpack":"^2.0.4",
        "mocha":"^3.0.0",
        "node-sass":"^4.5.3",
        "npm-run-all":"^4.0.2",
        "null-loader":"^0.1.1",
        "phantomjs-prebuilt":"^2.1.7",
        "postcss":"^6.0.12",
        "postcss-loader":"^2.0.6",
        "react-addons-test-utils":"^15.0.1",
        "react-test-renderer":"^16.0.0",
        "rimraf":"^2.5.2",
        "sass-loader":"^6.0.6",
        "sinon":"^4.0.0",
        "style-loader":"^0.18.2",
        "url-loader":"^0.5.7",
        "webpack":"^3.6.0",
        "webpack-bundle-size-analyzer":"^2.7.0",
        "webpack-dev-server":"^2.1.0-beta"
    },
    "dependencies":{  
        "@types/react":"^16.0.2",
        "babel-plugin-import":"^1.2.1",
        "babel-polyfill":"^6.23.0",
        "cross-env":"^5.0.5",
        "es6-tween":"^3.3.0",
        "eslint-watch":"^3.0.0",
        "image-webpack-loader":"^3.2.0",
        "immutable":"^3.8.1",
        "jwt-decode":"^2.1.0",
        "lodash":"^4.17.4",
        "material-ui":"0.19.3",
        "moment":"^2.18.1",
        "nock":"^9.0.13",
        "prop-types":"^15.5.8",
        "react":"^16.0.0",
        "react-addons-css-transition-group":"^15.4.2",
        "react-addons-shallow-compare":"^15.5.2",
        "react-bootstrap":"^0.31.3",
        "react-breadcrumbs":"^1.5.2",
        "react-dnd":"^2.4.0",
        "react-dnd-html5-backend":"^2.4.1",
        "react-dom":"^16.0.0",
        "react-ga":"^2.2.0",
        "react-helmet":"^5.0.0-beta",
        "react-hot-loader":"^3.0.0-beta.6",
        "react-redux":"^5.0.3",
        "react-router":"^3.0.0",
        "react-tap-event-plugin":"^3.0.2",
        "react-tooltip":"^3.3.0",
        "reactour":"^1.0.1",
        "redux":"^3.6.0",
        "redux-form":"^7.0.4",
        "redux-logger":"^3.0.6",
        "redux-mock-store":"^1.2.3",
        "redux-thunk":"^2.2.0",
        "styled-components":"^2.1.1",
        "superagent":"^3.5.0",
        "svg.js":"^2.6.2",
        "three":"^0.87.1",
        "throttle-debounce":"^1.0.1",
        "universal-cookie":"^2.0.8",
        "webpack":"^3.6.0",
        "whatwg-fetch":"^2.0.2"
    }
}
```

Along with React, I migrated to Enzyme 3.6.0 and started using `enzyme-adapter-react`, so in my entry file to tests `(src/config.test.js)` I did this:

```
import Enzyme from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

When I try to run tests with `jest` as I would usually, I get the error as in the title.

Also, if I try to use `jest-enzyme` and add this to my jest configuration:

```
"setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "./node_modules/jest-enzyme/lib/index.js",
```

I get another error :

> TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined.

So I am kinda stuck, whatever I try, I cannot make my tests work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I actually stumbled upon that issue and it didn't help me at all :/

Comment: Still working through this myself, but if I wrap the call to `configure` in an IIFE, the warning goes away. It seems like there's some monkey business where create-react-app (or jest?) is running the code in setupTests.js before performing the enzyme import. This doesn't totally solve the problem, since I'm apparently getting warnings from my test files before my setup is run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What helped me is the following: Rename alias from 'config' to something else e.g. 'my-config'. 
in moduleNameMapper:{ "my-config":"/src/config/test.js" ...}

and of course change imports in your js code. And should work.

It must have ben some name conflicts in enzyme or other dependencies.

Answer (score 14):

I was getting the same error. I found out my mistake was.

```
import shallow from 'enzyme';
```

I changed it to

```
import {shallow} from 'enzyme';
```

Answer (score 2):

Ran into this as well. In my case the problem was a bad setup that was redirecting any module whose name contained the substring `configuration` to my local environment-specific config.

In my specific case, with Jest, the fix was changing the jest `moduleNameWrapper` setting in `package.json` so that the key that redirected to my config was `^config$` instead of just `config`.

Comment: Even with "^config" was enough for me. Thanks. Saved my month!